# Passing variable between scripts

Tags: perl, shell

I've created a variable $date in Main.pl script that I would like to pass to Annotator.pl script. I use shell script to execute Annotator.pl.  I can't figure out how to pass $date to Annotator.pl. When I run `my $date = $ARGV[0];` in Annotator.pl I get the name of the current directory, however, `$date = $ARGV[1];` returns nothing.

Please see the code below. The date is important because it has to be exact and I can't figure out how to pass it to Annotator.pl. Thanks for your help.

Main.pl Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $sec; my $min; my $hour; my $mday; my $mon; my $year; my $wday; my $yday;    my $isdst;
    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
    $mon=$mon+1; $year = 1900+$year;
    if (length($mon)==1) {$mon="0".$mon;}
    if (length($mday)==1) {$mday="0".$mday;}
    if (length($hour)==1) {$hour="0".$hour;}
    if (length($min)==1) {$min="0".$min;}
    if (length($sec)==1) {$sec="0".$sec;}

    my $date = "$mon"."_"."$mday"."_"."$year"."-".$hour.$min.$sec;

    my $cmd5 = `perl MDL_unzip_annotate.sh /data/test_all_runs pVCF $date`;   print "$cmd5";
```

Shell script: MDL_unzip_annotate.sh that executes Annotator.pl

```
home="/data/test_all_runs" #location of the run directory from which the program is launched
   scripts="/data/test_scripts"  

     datapath=$1 #this is called in Main.pl as [test_all_runs]
     process=$2 #the process  

    if [[ "$process" == "pVCF" ]];then
            cd $datapath
            folders="$(ls)"
            cd $scripts
        for ff in $folders; do
            dname=$ff
                echo $dname
                if [  ! -f $dname ];then

                    cmd2="perl Annotator.pl $dname"
                    echo $cmd2

                    cmd2=`perl Annotator.pl $dname`
                    echo $cmd2
                fi
            done    
    done          

    fi
```

Annotator.pl script:

```
#!perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $date = $ARGV[1]; print "the date is######## ".$date."\n";
```

Comment: `perl MDL_unzip_annotate.sh /data/test_all_runs pVCF $date` is wildly dangerous -- concatenating your command into a string means you're calling `system()`, which runs `sh -c` with that string as an argument, which means you're vulnerable to shell injection attacks. Don't do that.

Comment: I'm a novice... please suggest how to pass $date to Annotator.pl. Thanks

Comment: Think about what happens if you populate your year from user input rather than the local time -- if the user runs the program with `1994$(rm -rf $HOME)` as the year, you don't want the system to actually invoke `rm`, but that's what'll happen if that string is passed to a shell -- and literal quoting is easy to work around.

Comment: Run your shell component through http://shellcheck.net/, and fix the bugs it identifies.

Comment: Also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: From what I can see you only pass one argument to `Annotator.pl`, the `$dname`.  So this is its `$ARGV[0]` and there is no `$ARGV[1]`.  The shell script should be receiving the `$date` in `$3` so you should be able to say `Annotator.pl $dname $3` (or rather first form a named variable out of `$3`).

Comment: should I avoid using shell?

Comment: @user3781528  I don't see any one particular reason that you'd need a shell script in the middle.  You can do everything that it does in your first Perl script. You would need to learn how to list and navigate directories but that isn't so hard.

Comment: If you aren't willing to learn to use shell safely, yes. It absolutely *can* be done safely, but there's a necessary skillset and understanding of the execution model. If you know perl, stick with perl.

Comment: I think all of this should be written as a single Perl program. It doesn't make sense to split it into three and use a mixture of shell and Perl.

Comment: The reason I'm using Shell is because I couldn't figure out how to define a path for unknown folder that is in a specific directory. So I use `my $tsv_directory = $home."test_all_runs/".$ARGV[0];` and
`my $tsv_files = $home."test_all_runs/".$ARGV[0]."/tsv_files.txt";` This work well with shell. Is there a way to accomplish the same with just using  Perl? I prefer using Perl. thanks

Comment: @user3781528: I don't understand. That is Perl code.

Comment: I think I figured out a quick fix. See my answer below. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using shell script I will use the following code to capture the name of the folder in a specific directory:

```
opendir my $dir, "/data/test_all_runs" or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @run_folder = readdir $dir;
closedir $dir;
my $last_one = pop @run_folder; print "The folder is".$last_one."\n";
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Great :)   Please note, `readdir` returns files without any path.  So to get workable lists you should prepend path as needed.  For example, `@filenames = map { "$path/$_" } readdir $dir`. Or you can `chdir $dirname` and then work with bare names.  But then _do not_ forget that your script's working directory is `$dirname`.